# Proving that if $ad-bc \neq 0$ then there is an unique solution to the linear system with 2 unknowns and 2 equations

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, systems-of-equations

**Exercise:** Prove that if $ad-bc \neq 0$, then the system

$$
ax + by = j \\
cx + dy = k
$$

has an unique solution.

---

This is from the very first subsection of Hefferon's Linear Algebra, and also the very first time I'm getting into rigorous mathematics. Now I am convinced that this could be shown from the defining property of the determinants, but that's way too far from my level.

My reasoning is as follows:

Solving the first equation for $x$ yields $x=(j-by)/a$. Substituting this expression in the second equation we get $c(j-by)/a+dy=k$. Solving this equation for $y$ gives $(ad-bc)y=ak-cj$. **Since** $ad-bc \neq 0$, it is safe to say that $y=(ak-cj)/(ad-bc)$. Back-substituting $y$ into the expression for $x$, we also get an unique value for $x$. Therefore $y=(ak-cj)/(ad-bc), x=(j-by)/a$ is the unique solution. QED?

However, I think my proof breaks down at some point because if $a=0$ then we cannot take the first step to solve the equation for $x$. The only part I asserted that we are not dividing by zero, is the part that I assumed $ad-bc \neq 0$.

I would like to take hints to make my proof watertight. I have peeked into the solutions manual and have noted that the author seperates the proof into seperate cases. I would like to know which cases I should consider and why. I would also like to know if it is provable without doing so.

Comment: You could handle the $a=0$ case, which would suggest that $y=\frac{j}{b}$ and $x=\frac{k-dy}{c}$, at least unless $b=0$ or $c=0$.  But if $a=0$ and either $b=0$ or $c=0$ then $ad-bc=0$

Comment: @Henry So there's that case, and the case in which none of the numbers a,b,c,d are zero, so I'd have to check two cases, right?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule#Explicit_formulas_for_small_systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first step, you assumed that $a$ in non zero, that's a problem. But your idea is not very far from the atual way. Let's multiply the first euation by $d$ and the second by $b$ to get $adx+dby=dj$ and $cbx+dby=bk$. Now we get $dj-adx=bk-cbx$ as both are equal to $dby$ so $dj-bk=(ad-bc)x$, and now you can divide by $ad-bc$.

Comment: I see. Would multiplying the first eq. by c and the second eq. by a lose any generality? And does manually finding an x and y (essentially the same way we both did) prove that there are unique solutions, like "the proof of the cake is in the eating"?

Comment: Nope! You will be then isolating $y$ first, and then $x$.  And when you specify the value of $x$ and the value $y$ means they're unique, as long as they do not varie, eg the system $x+2y=4, 2x+4y=8$ there are infinitely mani solutions given by $x=4-2t, y=t$, where you can plug different values for $t$ and still get solutions!

Comment: Actually this amounts to multiplying the matrix of the system by its adjugate matrix, which results in $(ad-bc) I_2$, where $I_2$ denotes the $2\times 2$ unit matrix…

Comment: @Bernard: my guess is that determinants and matrices may come later in the book.

Comment: @Henry: Probably. It was a comment to put things into perspective, just in case.